# How can I determine for a user svn the list of his locked files

Tags: linux, svn, svn-lock

What we need: in case of drop out a task or a development, the developer should unlock all files he is locking.

Is there a simple way to check for ***a specified USER the list of all files he is locking ?***

We are running Subversion on a Linux server using svn `version 1.8.11 (r1643975).`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`svnadmin lslocks`](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/svnadmin/c/lslocks/) (requires local access to the whole repository, i.e. you have to be an administrator) and then [`grep`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html) the output. Here is an example (I guess that you can search the web for a more complex one liner which will provide better output, e.g. with coloring):

`svnadmin lslocks PATH-TO-REPOSITORY | grep 'USERNAME' -B 2`

```
Path: /trunk/lockedfile.docx
UUID Token: opaquelocktoken:a0ec5b2a-fb50-ec4e-bbd2-20eb61bae743
Owner: user
--
Path: /branches/devbranch/anotherlockedfile.bmp
UUID Token: opaquelocktoken:d3222e08-96a7-ec4d-89f2-11777027d526
Owner: user
```

- Subversion allows you to [*steal* or *break* locks](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/advanced/locking/#svn.advanced.locking.break-steal), so it may be easier to allow your users to do this instead of using admin tools.
- BTW, in Subversion 1.8+ you can use [`svnadmin lock`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.lock.html) and [`svnadmin unlock`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.unlock.html) commands to manage locks.

Comment: thanks for the answar, the output of svn_admin lslocks cantain all needed informations, i should implement an abstracton layer to parse the output.
my need is to pass the user as argument and to get files(and comments) as a result.